# Cocoapod library on iOS error on header file only when i select iPhone device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I installed a cocoapod library (AppsFlyer). I added it to the project. When i select to run the app on my iPhone device the header file i imported in AppDelegate shows an error file not found. Nevertheless if i run the app on the device the error goes away and the app runs and AppsFlyer works ok. Second case. When i select to run the app on the Simulator the error goes away without running the app. On both cases the AppsFlyer works ok. My project is for arm64 iOS devices. Any ideas why this is happening? I need to get rid of this error when i select the iPhone device. Any help aprreciated.

Comment: Please provide a code sample and more details about the error. Is it a build error or a runtime error?

Comment: It is just a file not found error. I open the .m implementation file and i get the error only when selecting my iPhone device. Nevertheless when i run the app it works. It is like showing a false error.